# In c#, how to copy a file without extension?

Tags: c#

I've got a file named `test_file` which is a file without extension, the path is 'C:\share\'. And I want to copy it to a new folder so the code is:

```
File.copy(@"C:\share\test_file", @"C:\share\newFolder\test_file", true);
```

And it will throw an exception:

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path C:\share\newFolder\test_file

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Does the folder `C:\share\newFolder` exist? It needs to exist. The copy function won't create it for you. This has nothing to do with file extensions.

Comment: I agree with Andrew. Always read the exception to know what went wrong, or better yet, see the documentation per function to know all that could go wrong. I'm not the downvoter but I suspect the reason is that you showed no effort to solve it yourself (as you copied the answer to this problem and probably didn't even know it).

Comment: Yes, it exists indeed.

Comment: Sounds like C# treat `test_file` as a folder.

Comment: The destination includes file name, so it mustn't be considering it a folder. @Lazy_Clutch, what if the destination is `C:\share\test_file2`?

Comment: `DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path C:\share\newFolder\test_file` Exception speaks for itself sounds like a case of the developer not reading the exception message.. Create the folder then retest your code also if it's going to be placed on a different machine / remote machine I would suggest adding some `if(! Directory.Exist(){ "Then Force.Create"} the directory http://www.dotnetperls.com/directory-createdirectory

Answer (score 2):

Do following

```
//get name of directory where you are copying the file to

var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"C:\share\newFolder\test_file");
//create directory (following command will create all the missing folders in path)
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

File.Copy(@"C:\share\test_file", @"C:\share\newFolder\test_file", true);
```

Comment: No need to check if the directory exists, CreateDirectory() will create it if the directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Does `newFolder` exist?  I'm guessing it doesn't.  You need to create that folder, for example, using [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) it will create all necessary folders among given path. So it would be like:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\share\newFolder\\");
```

and then

```
File.Copy(@"C:\share\test_file", @"C:\share\newFolder\test_file", true);
```

Comment: better answer would have been to show example of the code preceded with the `if(!Directory.Exist` then create it then perform the copy method